# Can't access React Native developer menu after build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I can't open my dev menu via CMD+D or reload via CMD+R any longer. It stopped working after I deployed to the app store

Some more info:

- Shake gesture doesn't work
- Live reload doesn't work

What I have tried to fix it:

- Switched `Scheme` in Xcode to reference `Debug`
- tried other simulators
- downgrade/upgrades by a version ran
- ran `react-native upgrade` and said yes to every overwrite
- complete reinstall of all NPM modules
- Reset the simulator
- clean build
- reboot

## Edit:

Including AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"PresentApp"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Go to project-> scheme -> edit scheme -> and then make sure its debug mode..

Comment: tell me if it works

Comment: @Sarmad I apologize, I had already tried that but noted it wrong in the description. That solution didn't work.

Comment: Can you post your Appdelegate.m

Comment: @Sarmad, not a problem! I've added it above.